# Extract english dictionary words using macro in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to extract the english dictionary words from one column "A1" having many foreign languages' words to another column "B1". I want to do this on the whole column at once. I have macro that I have found but it only works for one cell not the whole column at once.
The macro is:

```
Sub ExtractDictionaryWords()
    Dim rWords As Range
    Dim rCell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set rWords = Range(Range("A1"), _
      Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
    For Each rCell In rWords
        If Not Application.CheckSpelling(rCell.Value) Then
            rCell.Clear
        End If
    Next
    On Error Resume Next
    rWords.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks). _
      Delete (xlShiftUp)
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set rCell = Nothing
    Set rWords = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The data is:

```
"A1"
abro
abroad
abroahsan
abroc
abrod
abrogated
abrogreat
abrunt
abrupt
abruptly
abruti
abrutis
abs
absa
```

The desired columns are by using macro at once on whole column range:

```
"A1"                     "B1"
abro                       
                        abroad
abroahsan
abroc
abrod
                        abrogated
abrogreat
                        abrunt
                        abrupt
                        abruptly
abruti
abrutis
abs
absa
zzz
ziyyyyy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following to do the shift. You will need to loop. Spelling checks are performed in a loop.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ExtractDictionaryWords()
    Dim rWords As Range, rCell As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rWords = .Range(.Range("A1"), _
                            .Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
        For Each rCell In rWords
            If Application.CheckSpelling(rCell.Value) Then
                rCell.Copy rCell.Offset(, 1)
                rCell.Clear
            End If
        Next
       ' On Error Resume Next
       ' rWords.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks). _
        Delete (xlShiftUp)
       ' .Range(.Range("B1"), _
               .Range("B65536").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks). _
                                                        Delete (xlShiftUp)
       ' On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

A more efficient way would be to move in one go using `Union` and clear cells in one go. This version was based on the fact previously you were deleting blank cells. For output as shown use above version.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ExtractDictionaryWords()
    Dim rWords As Range, rCell As Range, englishSpellings As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rWords = .Range(.Range("A1"), _
                            .Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
        For Each rCell In rWords
            If Application.CheckSpelling(rCell.Value) Then
                If Not englishSpellings Is Nothing Then
                    Set englishSpellings = Union(englishSpellings, rCell)
                Else
                    Set englishSpellings = rCell
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If Not englishSpellings Is Nothing Then
            englishSpellings.Copy .Range("B1")
            englishSpellings.Clear
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error Resume Next
        rWords.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks). _
        Delete (xlShiftUp)
        .Range(.Range("B1"), _
               .Range("B65536").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks). _
                                                        Delete (xlShiftUp)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I want the output to be that I've showed in my question.

Comment: Take the top version then and simply comment out the delete parts (which I have done)

Comment: @pnuts Thanks for pointing out. I am guessing this is not a coding issue though is it? Abs went across and I thought that was only an abbreviation (English language is not my strong suit). Is the dictionary based off the Oxford English? I guess I could go looking for a reason as you have piqued my curiosity.